# Should a single microservice be both public and internal simultaneously

Tags: design-patterns, microservices, restful-architecture

There are three microservices in place:

**Authors** 
which has the ability to SELECT and CRUD entity "author"

**Books** 
which has the ability to SELECT and CRUD entity "book"

**Mobile app host** 
built especially for the mobile client to respond with full data model requested, so that the mobile app would not 'enrich' data on its end.

Example: API 'MobileHost.getAllBooksOfGivenAuthor' will respond with both author name and book names, by calling 'Authors.getAuthorData(authorId)' and merging its data with 'Books.getBooksByAuthorIds(authorId)' resulting in a structure like this:

```
{ 
  "author" : {
    "name" : "Winner",
    "id" : 1
  },
  "books" : [
     {
       "name" : "Book A",
       "id" : "13231231"
     }
   ]
}
```

My **question** is: 
If the mobile client reads data through "Mobile app host" should it do "add author" through "Mobile app host" also, or is it ok to contact the "Authors" service directly? Should CRUD be proxied in such a case or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your goals.

From my experience, such “host” or “proxy” services tend to grow bigger and bigger without any real responsibility. Coupling many classes, functionalities and responsibilities in one place is definitely a bad idea — it will be difficult to maintain such service with time.

Moreover, it could be very difficult and resources ineffective to scale out instances of such service if, for example, only Authors service would need to be scaled out. So, if you are going to scale out different services and activities separately, then, sure, you don't need to proxy requests with only one service. You can have several proxy services, for instance, to scale out them separately or call Authors service directly and scale out them instead of proxy.

But if you don't see mentioned opportunities, then keep it as simple as possible — you will always be able to separate services and their proxies when it's time to do this, just keep everything separate inside.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response.
One more question to you:
apart of 'host' services, do you create API which are both internal and external? If you do, can you name a reason of why you made it this way?

Thanks.

Comment: We have mixed policy on API services because of caching. API caches some very frequent data and returns data from caches on query. Also it handles pagination and fetches from services only particular “pages” of data. If there is a service that doesn't require any cache system, we call it directly because it reduces amount of inter-service communication that could be pretty expensive on high loads. But our API services are designed to be separated at any moment, they follow facade design pattern. If we will notice that there is a huge load on small part of API service, we will take it out.